# Agreement between two groups of raters

Tags: agreement-statistics

What is the best method for assessing agreement between to groups? I have 2 ICU docs and 2 radiologists evaluating x-ray exams with yes/no outcome. I can use Cohen kappa for agreement within each group, but how can I assess agreement between the groups?